# Listing files greater than particular timestamp in file name?

Tags: linux, command-line, date, time, timestamps

I have a directory in **linux** which has a list of log files where log files get auto generated if some job runs. Each log file gets appended with the timestamp like "**JobName_TimeStamp**"

**UPDATED:**

```
job_2014-05-28_15:05:26.log
job_2014-05-28_15:06:58.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:02.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:57.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log

job1_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

I wanted to run a linux command to list all files greater than a particular timestamp?

**For Example 1** : I will pass two parameters , If the **TimeStamp** given is "**2014-05-28_15:08:00**" and **Job Name** is "**job**"

I should get the list as

```
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

**Example 2** : I will pass two parameters , If the **TimeStamp** given is "`2014-05-28_15:08:11`" and **Job Name** is "**job1**"

I should get the list as

```
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: If the filenames reflect the true timestamps of the files, then a better alternative may be to use that property directly i.e. something like `find -type f -newermt '2014-05-28 15:08:11'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code worked:

```
 for i in myjob*; do
           if [[ "myjob_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log" < "$i" ]]; then
                  echo $i
           fi
 done
```

Answer (score 2):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -nle '
    BEGIN {$t = "2014-05-28_15:08:00"}
    if (/_(.*?)\./) {
        print if $1 gt $t;
    }
' file
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

**Update**

A simple `perl` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $t = $ARGV[0];
my $l = qr/$ARGV[1]/;

while(<DATA>) {
    if (/${l}_/) {
        if (/_(.*?)\./) {
            print if $1 gt $t;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
job_2014-05-28_15:05:26.log
job_2014-05-28_15:06:58.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:02.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:57.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

Comment: I would be happy if the code is in linux command :)

Answer (score 2):

An awk (`mawk 1.3.3`) solution:

```
ls | awk -F'[_.]' '{printf "%s_%s\n", $2, $3}' | \
awk ' $0 > "2014-05-28_15:08:00" {print}'
```

Gives:

```
2014-05-28_15:08:01
2014-05-28_15:08:09
2014-05-28_15:08:10
2014-05-28_15:08:11
2014-05-28_15:08:12
2014-05-28_15:08:13
2014-05-28_15:08:14
2014-05-28_15:08:22
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` can do the majority of the work here:

```
jobname=job
timestamp=2014-05-28_15:08:00
param=${jobname}_${timestamp}.log
printf %s\\n "${param}" ./* |
sort -t_ -r -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n |
sed -n "\|./${jobname}_|{/${param}/q;p}"

###OUTPUT:

./job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
./job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
./job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
./job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
./job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
./job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
./job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
./job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
```

And the second example:

```
jobname=job1
timestamp=2014-05-28_15:08:11
param=${jobname}_${timestamp}.log
printf %s\\n "${param}" ./* |
sort -t_ -r -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n |
sed -n "\|./${jobname}_|{/${param}/q;p}"

###OUTPUT:

./job1_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
./job1_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
./job1_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
./job1_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-cnewer` with find:

```
find /mylogdir -name "job_*" -cnewer /mylogdir/job1_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log
```

Of course, this is finding files that were actually modified or had their metadata modified after `job1_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log` and not based on the file names. In your case this should work out just fine.